# could not insert module after kernel upgrade in VM

Tags: linux, kernel, virtualbox, upgrade

I was running Win7 as host and ubuntu14.04 as VM, on Virtualbox I upgraded the VM kernel. Thereafter, after compiling my kernel module again against the new kernel, i am not able to insmoding it.

It gives the following error :

```
vm@vm:~/Documents/kernelDev/CustomSockets$ sudo insmod CustomSocket.ko
insmod: ERROR: could not insert module CustomSocket.ko: Invalid module format
```

I dont see any eror message in dmesg logs.

I make sure that i am compiling the module against the correct kernel which is actually running.

```
vm@vm:/lib/modules/3.12.59UML$ pwd
/lib/modules/3.12.59UML
```

Makefile to compile the module:

```
obj-m += CustomSocket.o
all:
        make -C /lib/modules/3.12.59UML/build M=$(PWD) modules
clean:
    make -C /lib/modules/3.12.59UML/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

Can anyone pls help me out here ?

Comment: Absence of anything in `dmesg` sometimes means, that your module file is corrupted. Try to remove all build files and rebuilt the module.

Answer (score 0):

My bad, i was compiling against the wrong kernel version headers. Issue has been resolved.